# text displaying in every form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

i'm making an Ember app with a Rails back end. In one of the templates, I list the available teams from a database and beside each team put a form field for the user to enter some textual information. If I enter information in one form field, the text appears in all of the form fields (kind of like a multiple cursor experience).  That's one problem. Also, when I submit the button to attend one of the conferences, nothing's happening in the controller. I'm wondering if this is a related problem as Ember might think I'm trying to submit from multiple forms at one time due to the fact that these forms are acting as if they're the same form.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="conferences">

  <div class='span4'>
      {{#each item in model}}
      <li> {{#link-to 'conference' item}}
      {{ item.name }} 
      {{ partial 'conferences/form'}}
      {{/link-to }}</li>
    {{/each}}

         </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="span4 offset4">
   {{ outlet}}
   </div>

</script>
```

Inserted Form

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="conferences/_form">
<form class="form-horizontal" {{action "attend" on="submit"}}>
   <div class="controls">
      {{input value=username type="text"}}
  </div>   
  <button type="submit" class="btn">attend</button>
</form>
</script>
```

Conferences controller

```
 App.ConferencesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        attend: function() {    
         console.log('this is not logging, & no indication rails route is posted to)
        $.post("/join_conference_path", {

          username: this.get("username"),

        }).then(function() {
          document.location = "/";
        }, function() {

        }.bind(this));
       }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Having all input values synced to the same text happen due to fact that each input value is bound to the same property `username`.

This happens because all `_form` partials are rendered in the same context which is in your case `App.ConferencesController`. To make them render in individual context use `itemController` argument for `each` helper. See spec here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each

```
{{#each item in model itemController="conference"}}
```

In this case I suggest you rename your `App.ConferencesController` to `App.ConferenceController` which will represent individual context for each "item". Having it done this way your action will always use username input for specific "item" only.

Action may not trigger because by default all actions targets routes and not controllers. Try to add `target="controller"` attribute to `action` helper:

```
{{action "attend" on="submit" target="controller"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is helpful but there's something that's not clear or working. I added the itemController helper for "conference" and created that ConferenceController. That works. However, it only works when I click from a specific conference page `/conferences/42` for example, not when I click `attend` from the list of conferences, even though I'm using the same form partial in the list of pages.  If I click `attend` beside a conference from the list of conferences, it treats the button submission as a request to `show` that conference page, from which I then click `attend` to sign up

Comment: Note, I deleted ConferencesController and only now have ConferenceController.  Do you know why the same form (changed in the way you suggested) would trigger the attend action from the conference/42 show page, but not from the list of conferences page?